# Wordpress - add_rewrite_rule not passing $matches variable

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added this rewrite rule

```
add_rewrite_rule('^users/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=123&user_slug=$matches[1]','top');
```

The problem is that the correct page is being opened, however, the custom variable `user_slug` is not being passed. If I check the query vars with

```
global $wp;
print_r($wp->query_vars);
```

only page_id is printed out. How do I properly pass that other variable there?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are registering your custom query variable with wordpress before you make the rewrite call:

```
add_rewrite_tag( '%user_slug%', '([^/]*)' );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag